# USB C HUB delivery safe?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, apple-id

so I bought a USB-C hub for my MacBook Pro 2017, specifically, this one:

http://www.qacqoc.com/product/gn30h-premium-usb-c-hub-with-power-delivery-3-superspeed-usb-3-0-for-macbook-12-inch-gray/

it has a power delivery USB-C port, and I'm wondering if it safe for my Macbook to always use that port when I have the hub plugged in (so I can use the other USB-C port on the mac for other purposes) or it is better to plug power directly into the Macbook? any technical differences?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the USB-C hub is defective or not standards compliant, there should be no harm in plugging in the power supply there. It is totally safe and an intended functionality!